# Usage of 2 cursors to create 2 tables in email

Tags: html, sql-server

I would like to ask you how to create an email with 2 tables in MS SQL 2014.

Right now I do have email with created table that is sent to particular recipients and I want to add another table with text that is only sent to recipients that are affected. 
currently I use cursor for the first table.

i want to use second cursor for the other condition but I do not know how to combine them.
st            N'' +

```
                select @count = count(*) from <table> with (nolock) where birthday = 'GIFT'

                if (@count > 0)
                BEGIN
```

Currently I am using CURSOR, but i need to have 2 cursors and I dont know how to mix them into one email.

First cursor I use for the first table and second I want to use for the second table in the same email.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Define recipients, pls. Giving out table names (rather than synonyms) can expose parts of your meta data to the internet...instead of the intranet...explain why before the how, since a qualified SQL DBA can just read an error log to accomplish the same without exposing the metadata).

Comment: If this question is for [tag:sql-server] then please remove [tag:mysql] to prevent confusion.

Comment: What is the desired output? A string? An html string?

Comment: I would suggest to parse the the whole mail text into a nvarchar variable - this way you can handle all kinds of conditions. Afterwards assign the variable to the mail.